# Delete record from SQLite database using form button

Tags: php, sqlite

Created a form that successfully inserts a record from a form into a SQLite database. Trying to also add a delete button but i am unsure on how to execute the query properly. Here is my code:

**index.php**

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="input" value="Input">
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
```

**post.php**

```
if (!empty($_POST['input'])) {
  header("location:index.php");
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO stock (name, gender, age) VALUES   (:name, :gender, :age)");
  $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name'],
                                       ':gender' => $_POST['gender'],
                                       ':age' => $_POST['age']));
}

elseif (!empty($_POST['delete'])) {
  header("location:index.php");
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM stock WHERE name = ':name' AND gender = ':gender' AND age = 'age'");

}
```

Comment: Start by removing the quotes around your binds.

Comment: Done, how do i execute the delete query?

Comment: Same way you did in your insert.

Comment: Plus, use `isset()` rather than `!empty()` and add `exit;` after each header.

Comment: Oh LOL. Thank you. I wasn't sure if i should be executing the array again

Comment: You're welcome. When a certain button/input is "set", it will execute what's been called ;-)

Comment: If everything that's been said here in comments have in fact solved the issue, you may delete the question.

Comment: If i insert the exit; though after the header inside the if statement, the code wont be executed? i should create another condition for the header?

Comment: Place/move your headers after each query and add `exit;`. Once one of them is successfully executed, it will then redirect to the specified URL and stop any further execution of the rest of the script.

Comment: also when changing !empty() to isset() i get a redirect page loop

Comment: That's probably because your code's execution file is called "index.php" and you've the form inside it too. Rather than header, test with removing the headers and replace it with `echo "Success...."; exit;`

Comment: Oops solved. Forgot to delete the NOT operator. Thanks!

Comment: You can delete the question, unless you want it closed and marked as solved?

Comment: Didn't think users had the ability to delete questions only vote to remove. And i was told to leave questions up as this is a helping community so ill mark it as solved. Thanks

Comment: Well I can post my comments in an answer below and you can accept it.

Comment: Yes please, if you could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isset()` rather than `!empty()` When a certain button/input is "set", it will execute what's been called  and add `exit;` after each header.

Using "exit;" will avoid further code execution.

Since you're getting a redirection loop, use `echo "Success"; exit;` instead, or use another file to redirect to.

You should remove the quotes around your binds also:

```
WHERE name = :name AND gender = :gender
```